# Correct way to pass info

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

So I've been thinking.

When you create a form and use applicaton.run(form1). And within that form1 you open another form2 and hide form1. Within form2 you open another form3 and hide form 2. But in form3 you want to use the info(variables) provided in form1 which is not ?accessible? correct me if I'm wrong.

I've thought about several ways, but I dont think they are the correct way.

1. Save the info from form1 in a static class.
2. Create all forms objects in the main class and close/run them 1 by 1.
3. Pass the info(variables) from form1 to form2 to form3.

What is the correct way to do this?

I am sorry if its hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. If these are dialog forms shown as modals and there's only one or two variables then it's often OK to store the values as properties in the class for that form and just examine it in the same way as you with DialogResult on a standard MessageBox form.

If its more complicated or the forms are staying open, then you'd want to create an object and pass that to the forms. Remember objects are passed by reference, so if you create a class called MyDataContainer, and then create an instance in the main form, then pass that instance to the other forms, it is the same instance in each of those forms. So if form3 updates that instance, the other forms will be able to see those changes too.

Ps: avoid the static route, there is very rarely a valid use case for that.

Comment: Yes, understood. I always hesitate on which way I should pick. This makes things a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no "correct" way to do it. All the ways you mentioned could work.  One additional way would be to maintain one static list of all forms.  That way any form could locate any other form by searching the list for it.  More specifically a `Dictionary<string,Form>` where string is a unique identifier for the form, might prove useful.

That said,  it all really comes down to your design goals.  Typically it's best to go with the simplest solution that accomplishes your design goals.

Comment: Thank you that eases my mind quite a bit! I will use the simplest solution that accomplishes my design goals.

Comment: @tuyen.  Glad to be of help.  An upvote would be appreciated.

Comment: Would love to, but I dont have enough rep for it to publicly show. It does say its recorded.

Comment: @TuyenPhan No worries.  My pleasure.  Welcome to stack overflow.